# How to do Firebase cloud messaging with Xamarin Forms? (ios and android)

Tags: firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm new to firebase and xamarin. Trying to make a chat application for android and ios but I dont know where to begin and there isn't much documentation on this.

So far I have made a login and registration with Firebase's realtime database.

The messaging system works like this:
 - Client registers to the app.
 - The admin of the app will assign a registered salesmen to the client
 - Now that client and salesmen will be able to chat with each other.

I've seen the Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging NuPackage so I'm sure it's possible but I don't even know where to begin.

Any help will be appreciated, also let me know if you want to see any of my current code for reference.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/firebase-cloud-messaging

Comment: @Jason Will this also work with ios?

Comment: You can also take a look at OneSignal. Very nice push API (uses Firebase api under the hood), easy to implement on xamarin forms and got a really sufficient free plan to begin with a production app. 

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/xamarin-sdk-setup

Comment: For the Firebase cloud messaging with ios, you could check the link below. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client

Comment: how did you get on with this? I need to do something similar